# Storing data from a JSON Feed locally Android

Tags: java, android, xml, json

Hi I'm trying to find out about storing a JSON Feed locally on the phone, so that it may then be used globally and offline. For example in iOS I wrote it to a empty pList and I'm looking for the equivalent of that on Android.
 For example is it better to write to XML or create a .JSON file and how do I go about writing to/reading this file to then reuse the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save data in DB, or you can also save json file and read data when required.

Answer (score 1):

I have a class that grabs the json feed and then I turn it into a string and save it in a database along with the cookie that is currently used. So I can re-check the log in status onResume().

Answer (score 1):

The easiest mode to store it is to save it in SharedPreferences.
It is the fast and save / secure way to store String values which JSON is ; )

Answer (score 1):

Google I/O App for Android: [iosched](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) is a good example for you, it use .json in /res/raw to store its data.

Also, *google-gson* will save you much time if you work with json data and you will feel surprise when developing.

Finally, if you need to know how to reuse the data globally and offline. This video [Android REST client applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) is really useful.